# ms-access vba Eval function behavior

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a public function in an Access form

```
Public Function PopupProcess() as long
  MsgBox Me.ActiveControl
  PopupProcess = 1
End Function
```

When I call

```
eval("forms('MyForm').popupprocess")
```

it shows a message box 2 times. Does anybody know why it does that?

I Have Access 2003 with SP3.

EDIT : Main idea is to call function from that form for Custom Commandbar control OnAction.
Maybe you have better way to call function from a form for commandbar control.

Comment: Is there some other function in the form that may also be calling the function? 

For example, if you add an empty function to the form (say, "Public Function DoesNothing") and call eval("forms('MyForm').DoesNothing"), do you get a message box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very long standing bug that’s been around since the days of access 97, (about 4-5 versions of access).

The solution here is to NEVER use the forms qualifier, simply place the following in your on action event, and you’ll be just fine

```
=PopUpProcess()
```

Note that you must precede it with=, and the suffix must have the brackets  ()

Keep in mind that you can actually use behavior to your advantage. The function that runs is going to be from the form that currently has the focus on the screen. That means you can have different forms with the same name of the function, and whichever form has the focus, that function with that name will run from that forms code module.

Even better, if one of the forms does not have that function as public in the forms code module,  then the function in a standard code module is used. So you might have nine forms, that all use the standard one function in the main standard code module. However, the 10th form might need to run special code, so you simply place that function code in the form’s code module as public and it will run in place of the public on in the standard code module.

This approach allows you to build a single custom menu bar that applies to many different forms, but those many forms will run different code on from that custom menu bar. This also encourages you to place the menu code in the form it belongs.

So to solve your problem, simply don’t use a form’s qualifier, and use the above format.

Note that you can pass Parameters from those functions also, for example

```
=PopUpProcess(‘hello’)
```

And then declare the function as:

```
Public Function PopUpProcess(strParm as string)
```

Keep in mind that the function and syntax and all of what I stated above also applies to when you use the on action in a ribbon for access 2007.

Comment: Very nice indeed ! But I have the impression that Access 2007 has a changed behaviour, and that the public functions of a form are no more usable outside of VBA (e.g. as the source of a calculated control). Can someone confirm ?

Comment: I am not aware of any change in this behavior with regards to 2007.  For a public function in a form called mytest, then =mytest() can be the source of a control on that form. You still must use the public keyword, and we are taking about a form that has the current focus. As far as I can tell, I don't see any different behaviors in how this works in 2003,or 2007.

Comment: I almost never disagee with Albert, but I think this is TERRIBLE advice. Specifity in your code execution is a big deal, and you should write what you mean. For situations like this (a toolbar), I would write a public function that calls whatever is needed, and it would be in a public module, not in a form's module (though I might write it so that one parameter would be the name of the form I wanted to call it in).

Comment: Albert, are you sure your advice here works in a command bar? The context in which they run is very, very different from the one in which expressions in forms are evaluated.

Comment: Yes this works for menu/tool bars. You specify the menu bar/ribbon for that form. This is an ideal setup for when you start to move buttons from the form up to the menu bar or ribbon. This also means you do not have to adopt ribbon call backs. Even better is this setup means whatever form has the focus will have the function run and thus multiple forms can use the same ribbon (or menu bar) but have different code run in the particular form such as custom delete code. If the code does not belong in the form then so be it, but for code that belongs in the current form this is an ideal choice.

Answer (score 1):

No idea.  What happens if you call it like this?

```
Call Forms("MyForm").PopupProcess
```

Try using the CallByName function, instead of eval, to call your function.  It should only fire your function once, and it will still allow you to parameterize the form name and the function or sub name:

```
CallByName Forms("MyForm"), "PopupProcess", VbMethod
```

Comment: The above can’t work in this case. The poster is talking about custom menu bars, not a button on a form. In custom menu bars you only have the onAction setting, and for it to call your code you must use an expression, not “Call subname”.

Comment: You could call a public function that calls the function on form.